# C++ disable an overloaded operator in child class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this String class where I overloaded the operator + to concat strings.

```
class String {
    private:
      char* value;
    
    public:
      String(char*);
      String operator+(String&);
    };

int main() {
  String s1("Hello");
  String s2(" world!");
  String s3 = s1 + s2;

  cout << s3 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

result:
Hello world!

I declared a new class GoodString, a child of the String class. I want to disable the overloaded operator. I tried some stuff but without success.
Any suggestion? thank you!

Comment: You could declare it as an overridden and private or deleted function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! And tbh, I think declaring it private is actually smart, I should have thought about it. Delete functions, first time I hear about them.

Comment: [Deleting functions showed up in 2011](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions). It is usually preferable because the error messages tend to be more direct and readable than the `private` and do not implement approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

1. Override with `private` visibility

```cpp
class GoodString : public String {
private:
    String operator+(String&);
};
```

2. `delete` the operator (since c++11)

```cpp
class GoodString : public String {
public:
    String operator+(String&) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as an overridden and private method. In addition, next time add your code for the `GoodString` class.